# Why Meraki Switches have DNS defined in their settings?

Tags: switch, meraki

What a Meraki switch would do with DNS?
switching has nothing to do with Domain name resolution..
the only thing I can come up with, is that their switches probably using some type of domain address instead of IP to connect to their clouds???!!
[image]

thanks

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

Merakis are managed via a centralized system hosted in the cloud.  DNS is the way by which the Meraki endpoints (...whether switches, firewalls, AP's or cameras) connect back to that cloud system.  It's also key to said endpoints being able to reach alternate management points should failures or excessive load occur in Meraki's infrastructure.